# number of dictionaries to how to create new JSON file in to one list and remove last comma from JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, file, dictionary

I have large number of dictionaries so i created new Json file with that dictionaries, but the dictionaries are not adding in to one list and while creating new json file it won't remove the last comma

Here i'm writing how my data looks like, Can anyone suggest better way

Thanks in Advance help would be appreciate!!!

```
json_dict = {}
for li in jsonli:
  json_dict.update(li)

with open(r"D:\Users\laki.aya\Desktop\Invalidemail\stc.json", 'a+') as fout:
  fout.write(json.dumps(json_dict, indent = 4,default=str))
  fout.write(',\n')
  fout.close()
```

I'm getting output like this below:

```
    {
    "email": "zxxxccxxcc@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 5123456
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-12-01"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "email": "zyyyyyyuser@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 188882272
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-09-16"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "email": "z3@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 100000708
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-11-30"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
},
```

I'm expecting data should in one list and remove the last comma

Expected

```
[  
    {
    "email": "zxxxccxxcc@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 5123456
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-12-01"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "email": "zyyyyyyuser@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 188882272
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-09-16"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "email": "z3@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 100000708
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-11-30"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
}
]
```

please suggest better way

Answer (score 0):

Just use `json.dump` inside your file `open` clause -

```
import json

# some example data
json_data = [{'name':'Joe', 'age':40}, {'name':'Jane', 'age':50}]

with open('json_file_out.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(json_data, fout)
```